# BeepBeep and ErlyDB integration issue

Tags: mysql, erlang, erlydb, beepbeep

Further to my adventures with Erlang and ErlyDB. I am attempting to get ErlyDB working with [BeepBeep](http://github.com/davebryson/beepbeep/)

My ErlyDB setup works correctly when run outside of the BeepBeep environment (see [Debugging ErlyDB and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228893/debugging-erlydb-and-mysql)). I have basically take the working code and attempted to get it running inside BeepBeep.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
handle_request("index",[]) ->
  erlydb:start(mysql,Database),
  erlydb:code_gen(["thing.erl"],mysql), 
  NewThing = thing:new_with([{name, "name"},{value, "value"}]),
  thing:save(NewThing),
  {render,"home/index.html",[{data,"Hello World!"}]};
```

When I call the URL, the response outputs "Server Error". 
There is no other error or exception information reported.

I have tried wrapping the call in try/catch to see if there is an underlying error - there is definitely an exception at the call to **thing:new_with()**, but no further information is available.

The stacktrace reports:

```
{thing,new,[["name","value"]]}
{home_controller,create,1}
{home_controller,handle_request,3}
{beepbeep,process_request,4}
{test_web,loop,1}
{mochiweb_http,headers,4}
{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}
```

Comment: The bit that really puzzles me is that I can take ErlyDB code from an Erlang module that works, and the moment I put it inside the Controller, the server error appears.

Answer (score 2):

Use pattern matching to assert that things work up to the call to thing:new/1:

```
ok = erlydb:start(mysql,Database),
ok = erlydb:code_gen(["thing.erl"],mysql),
```

You include only the stack trace, look at the exception message as well. I suspect that the error is that you get an 'undef' exception. But check that it is so. The first line in the stack trace indicates that it is a problem with calling thing:new/1 with ["name", "value"] as argument.

It is slightly odd that you show one clause of handle_request that is not calling home_controller:create/1 as per `{home_controller,create,1}` in the stack-trace. What do the other clauses in your handle_request/2 function look like?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Using the patterns as above works nicely.
One of the problems seems to be that the exception is just swallowed by the server ... The browser reports server error, but the server command line shows no output at all. Makes things a bit tricky to debug.

Comment: Why not use dbg with return value and process event trace then?

Comment: What is dbg?
I am pretty new to Erlang.

Comment: Erlang has an interface to debugging called dbg. See this question for some usage examples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274681/query-an-erlang-process-for-its-state/1274939

Comment: See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html for dbg. For example try
dbg:tracer(), dbg:tpl(ModuleName, [{'_', [], [{return_trace}]}]), dbg:p(all, c). to see all calls to a given module's functions, and their return values on the console. This is usually very helpful in figuring out what and when went wrong.