# Getting gen_server/gen_fsm state for debugging

Tags: erlang, gen-server

Is it possible to obtain the current state of a `gen_server` process (presumably by sending some system message)? It could be useful when debugging.

Of course, I can add a message which returns the current state to `handle_call`:

```
get_state(Server) -> gen_server:call(Server, '$get_state').

%% in every gen_server I want to debug
...
handle_call('$get_state', _From, State) ->
  {reply, State, State};
...
```

but is there something built-in (even if it is a bit hacky)?

Comment: What's wrong with connecting to the gen_server process with the built-in debugger and actually debugging it?

Comment: No GS in the embedded system, so no debugger (or can it run without graphics?).

Comment: If the node is accessible from the outside, you can debug it from a remote machine with GS - IMHO it's one of the strong points of Erlang.

Comment: And if the debugger does not work you can always use set a trace pattern using dbg, however both of these methods require you to view the state by sending a command. If you do not want this you can use sys:get_status as gleber describes below.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1274681/113848).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a function that returns the state directly: [`sys:get_state/1,2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/sys.html#get_state-1). It accepts pid or name of the process and can optionally be given a timeout.

Answer (score 30):

Use [`sys:get_status/1,2` function](http://erldocs.com/R14B/stdlib/sys.html?i=0&search=sys%3aget#get_status/1). It's definition is:

```
get_status(Name,Timeout) -> 
    {status, Pid, {module, Mod}, [PDict, SysState, Parent, Dbg, Misc]}
```

`SysState` will contain state of the process. It works for all processes using OTP behaviors and other processes implementing `proc_lib` and `sys` requirements.