# What's the best erlang approach to being able to identify a processes identity from its process id?

Tags: debugging, erlang, process, ets, process-dictionary

When I'm debugging, I'm usually looking at about 5000 processes, each of which could be one of about 100 gen_servers, fsms, etc.  If I want to know WHAT an erlang process is, I can do:

```
process_info(pid(0,1,0), initial_call).
```

And get a result like:

```
{initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,5}}
```

...which is all but useless.

More recently, I hit upon the idea (brace yourselves) of registering each process with a name that told me WHO that process represented.  For example, player_1150 is the player process that represents player 1150.  Yes, I end up making a couple million atoms over the course of a week-long run.  (And I would love to hear comments on the drawbacks of boosting the limit to 10,000,000 atoms when my system runs with about 8GB of real memory unused, if there are any.)  Doing this meant that I could, at the console of a live system, query all processes for how long their message queue was, find the top offenders, then check to see if those processes were registered and print out the atom they were registered with.

I've hit a snag with this: I'm moving processes from one node to another.  Now a player process can have 3 different names; player_1158, player_1158_deprecating, player_1158_replacement.  And I have to make absolutely sure I register and unregister these names with precision timing to make sure that a process is always named and that the appropriate names always exist, AND that I don't try to register a name that some dying process already holds.  There is some slop room, since this is only used for console debugging of a live system  Nonetheless, the moment I started feeling like this mechanism was affecting how I develop the system (the one that moves processes around) I felt like it was time to do something else.

There are two ideas on the table for me right now.  An ets tables that associates process ids with their description:

```
ets:insert(self(), {player, 1158}).
```

I don't really like that one because I have to manually keep the tables clean.  When a player exits (or crashes) someone is responsible for making sure that his data are removed from the ets table.

The second alternative was to use the process dictionary, storing similar information.  When my exploration of a live system led me to wonder who a process is, I could just look at his process dictionary using process_info.

I realize that none of these solutions is functionally clean, but given that the system itself is never, EVER the consumer of these data, I'm not too worried about it.  I need certain debugging tools to work quickly and easily, so the behavior described is not open for debate.  Are there any convincing arguments to go one way or another (other than the academic "don't use the *_*, it's evil" canned garbage?)  I'd be happy to hear other suggestions and their justifications.

Comment: Be careful with dynamically generated atoms. If you generate atoms like player_<id|counter>, you will eventually run out of atoms since the VM never "garbage collects" them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try out [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc/), it's a very convenient application for keeping process metadata.

A process can be registered with several names and you can associate arbitrary properties to a process (where the key and value can be any erlang term). Also gproc monitors the registered processes and unregisters them automatically if they crash.

Comment: true ! full documentation of GPROC: http://rustyklophaus.com/articles/20090916-GProcErlangGlobalProcessRegistry.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're debugging `gen_server`s and `gen_fsm`s while they're still running, I would implement the `handle_info` functions for these behaviors.  When you send each process a `{get_info, ReplyPid}` tuple, the process in question can send back a term describing its own state, what it is, etc.  That way you don't have to keep track of this information outside of the process itself.

---

Isac mentions there is already [a built in way to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254070/getting-gen-server-gen-fsm-state-for-debugging)

Comment: You might as well just get the state of the process using this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254070/getting-gen-server-gen-fsm-state-for-debugging

Comment: I didn't realize such a thing existed, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: One of the motivations for using the registry to name the processes was that using handle_info or handle_cast as the mechanism for retrieving this info, I would not be able to query any process that was either backlogged with messages or waiting for a message (which I don't do in this system, but it is a potential issue.  Since I do occasionally have to debug processes whose message queues have filled with cruft, the on-demand approach was scrapped.