# How do I write a game loop in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, game-loop

I want to code a game in Haskell where every iteration of the loop computes the state of the world. I thought I should create a function:

```
gameLoop :: World -> World
-- ...
```

and have `main :: IO ()` call it:

```
main = do
    gameLoop -- ...
```

But the problem is that I'm missing some fundamental understanding of how to wrap the `gameLoop` function so that it returns `main`'s parameter value.

How would one go about creating a game loop in Haskell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll probably want something like this

```
import Control.Monad.Loops

main = iterateM_ 
       (\w -> displayWorld w >> return (gameLoop w))
       initWorld
-- iterateM_ ((>>) <$> displayWorld <*> return . gameLoop) initWorld
```

Or if you don't want to use the whole monad-loops package (even though it rocks)

```
main = loop initWorld
  where loop w = displayWorld w >> loop (gameLoop w)
```

Basically you're just drawing the world, then looping again to with the next state.

More likely you want something like this though

```
 -- False when the user wants to exit the game
 keepGoing :: World -> Bool

 main = iterateUntilM_ keepGoing displayLoop initWorld
   where displayLoop w = displayWorld w >> return (gameLoop w)
```

Since otherwise you can't stop :)

Answer (score 4):

I think what you declared is a state transition function, and the game loop itself should be a recursive function.  The general idea looks like this:

```
initialState :: World
nextState :: World -> World
isFinalState :: World -> Bool

gameLoop world | isFinalState world = -- ...
               | otherwise = do
                     drawScene world
                     gameLoop (nextState world)

main = gameLoop initialState
```

In `initialState` the initial world can be constructed with initial parameters, etc. And in `nextState` you can process player inputs (keyboards, etc.) which will change the state of the world.  `isFinalState` is used to detect whether we should exit the game loop.

This structure is somewhat similar to that frequently used in Erlang, e.g. [Query an Erlang process for its state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274681/query-an-erlang-process-for-its-state)

Comment: Ps, that's not a tail recursive function. It's equivalent to `a >> recurse` where `(>>)` is the last function, not `recurse`.

Comment: @jozefg Thanks for pointing out, I am not that familiar with Haskell details :-)